# Cannot Restore DB to RDS Instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, restore

I am getting below error when trying to restore DB from S3 Bak file -

100 percent processed.
 [2018-11-12 19:32:21.677] Processed 32980832 pages for 
 database 'RDSBackup', file 'SourceDB_NEW' on file 1.
 [2018-11-12 19:32:21.680] 
 Processed 4547 pages for database 
 'RDSBackup', file 'SourceDB_NEW_log' on file 1. 
 [2018-11-12 19:32:22.013] 
 RDSBackup_FULL_COPY_ONLY_20181112_010009.bak: 
 S3 processing has been aborted.

Error started after the source DB version changed from  SQL2012 Enterprise to SQL2016 Standard.

Comment: "processing has been aborted" is not enough information for your peers to help you solve. Unless the instance you're restoring to is *not* SQL Server 2016 or above (check `SELECT @@VERSION;`), you should contact RDS support. If the version is 2012 or 2014, you're going to have to upgrade or migrate to a different server with a newer version. You will never be able to restore a 2016 backup to a 2012 or 2014 server.

Comment: Might be that the database is using an enterprise feature of 2012 that is still an enterprise feature in 2016; hence the error.

Comment: I get This when I run select @@version 

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU9-GDR) (KB4293805) - 14.0.3035.2 (X64)   Jul  6 2018 18:24:36   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I escalated this issue to AWS. As per the latest update, they have made some changes to RDS and I could restore the DB even with a large log file (300GB). 
Link for the newest update details is below - 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/rds-sql-server-has-two-new-exciting-backup-and-restore-enhancements/

Alternate solution - At first, I was asked to try to restore with a smaller log file. I shrunk the logs and the restore worked.
Although AWS engineers asked me to keep a check on the logfile size, they made some changes to RDS so as to accommodate S3 bak files with relatively large size as well.